# German equivalent for "buzz-in"?

Tags: single-word-request

While working at the US I learned this very useful word, "to buzz somebody in". It means that you press the button which remotely opens the front door of your house, and as long as the person waiting outside hears the buzzing of the marget that unlocks the door he or she can enter.

So, it is quite common to ask somebody "to buzz you in", especially while standing in front of the door on a cold day -- "Hey, Max, this is me, Alexander, can you buzz me in"? :)

I have never heard any similar word in German.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't an equivalent *verb*.

However, for the situation you describe, it's usual for Alexander to say:

> Hi Max, ich bin's, Alexander, kannst Du mal drücken?

Not sure what the hen and what the egg is in this context, but the buzzer is known as the "Drücker".

There also is the literal translation "Summer", but I have the impression that this is not widely used in common speech.

Another common variant is to just use "let s.o. in", i.e. to say:

> Hi Max, ich bin's, Alexander, kannst Du mich mal reinlassen?

This has the additional advantage that it is more readily understandable without context. For example if you're telling someone that your colleague forgot his key and you had to buzz him in, it's better to say:

> Gestern musste ich Armin wieder reinlassen; er hatte seinen Schlüssel
>   schon wieder vergessen.

The following would sound strange:

> *Gestern musste ich wieder drücken; Armin hatte seinen Schlüssel schon
>   wieder vergessen.

Comment: Und wenn Du mehrere gleichzeitig reinläßt, ist das eine "Drückerkolonne" ;)

Comment: 'but the buzzer is known as the "Drücker"' - never heard that one. To me, that's the "Türöffner" or "Türknopf" or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of *"drücken"* may be regional. In the south west of Germany where I live it is understood but I can't remember I ever heard it used. We usually put it like that when speaking through a talk-back:

> Ich bin's[, der Alexander]. (*which implies, that you want to get in*)

Often the name is also omitted (*sic*). Only in case you really need someone to operate the buzzer we'd say:

> Kannst Du mir [bitte noch einmal] aufmachen?
>   Mach mir mal auf [bitte].  (*this variant should only be used in a familiar setting*)

Answer (score 0):

ich bin's, Alexander, kannst Du mir aufdrücken?

ist das nächste, was mir einfällt. Die Lautmalerei des buzz hat es nicht, aber im Gegensatz zu `kannst Du mich einlassen` ist ein mechanisches Türöffnen hier als Bedeutung nahezu ausgeschlossen - wenn man packetbeladen, vielleicht vor einer gläsernen Tür den anderen direkt anspricht könnte auch noch das physische Aufdäuen gemeint sein, aber durch eine Gegensprechanlage gesagt sollte es jeder verstehen.

Um Macs `"kannst Du mal drücken"` zu verstehen benötigt man m.E. ein wenig mehr Kontext, der bei `aufdrücken` schon dabei ist.

Answer (score 0):

`Kannst Du mich reinlassen?`, or similar is the most common phrase for that, the buzzing is not emphasized or exists as a special verb.

Variation:

`Kannst Du mir mal aufmachen, bitte?`

But the following is possible:

`Kannst Du nochmal den Türdrücker betätigen`, die Tür hat geklemmt.

```
Bitte den Türöffner drücken, ich komme nicht rein.
```

oder

```
  Bitte nochmal drücken, das ging zu schnell.
```